# C++ : Converting UTF-8 Text to UTF-8 or UTF-16

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf-16

In our application, we are reading a file which has chinese file name, say **你好.txt**. This file name is passed by UI to backend C++ application.

UI is passing it as **ä½ å¥½.txt** that is **UTF-8 TEXT** not UTF-8.
So when I am trying to read the same file, it is showing "File not exist" in C++.

When I search through net, there are lot of methods available to convert from and to UTF-8. But I couldn't find any suitable methods which converts from **UTF-8 TEXT**.

Can any one please help to resolve this?

Ans:
Using the below code i converted to chinese. And our server method can able to read the file.

```
template <typename T>
void fromUTF8(const string& source, basic_string<T, char_traits<T>, allocator<T>>& result)
{
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<T>, T> convertor;
    result = convertor.from_bytes(source);
}
```

But again, i have one more place i need to construct the JSON with chinese,
We are using the below code RapidJSON:

```
string jsonData = "";
StringBuffer sb;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(sb);
writer.StartObject();
writer.Key("profileid");
witer.String(strOutProfileId.c_str());

writer.Key("profilename");
writerUTF16.String(profilename.c_str());

writer.EndObject();

jsonData = sb.GetString();
```

JSON:
{
    "profileid": "DUP1",
    "profilename": "sample"
}
If it is in english it is working fine. 
I want to construct like below:

```
{
    "profileid": "DUP1",
    "profilename": "不用客气"
}
```

profile name stored in wstring. then how to modify the rapidjson writer to write this chinese.

Comment: What is UTF-8 TEXT? Never heard of that. Are you sure it is not UTF-7?

Comment: https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter          For word Hello in chinese: UTF-8 text is    ä½ å¥½ and UTF-8 is \xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd

Comment: I think that for UTF-8 text you mean UTF-8 written with ANSI characters, while with UTF-8 you use the escaped bytes directly

Comment: _UI is passing it as ä½ å¥½.txt._ I believe the outcome is in UTF-8 and somewhere interpreted with wrong encoding (e.g. ANSI). Nevertheless, this doesn't change the bytes of outcome - they just have to be interpreted with the correct encoding...

Comment: The UI is giving you an UTF-8 encoded string. As@ cbuchart said, the "UTF-8 Text" is just UTF-8 rendered badly. (e.g.: ä = Unicode: U+00E4, UTF-8: C3 A4). You should read the output from your UI as binary blob, the value you are seeing probably results from just printing the output without correct interpretation. It is also possible that the UI garbles the file name in which case you should find out how to read filenames properly (this will change from system to system). Ideally could you paste your code here?

Comment: Would you be using a Windows system?

Comment: Indeed, `ä½ å¥½.txt` is the proper UTF-8 encoded form of `你好.txt` being misinterpreted in an ANSI charset, such as Latin-1.  Simply reinterpret the ANSI bytes as UTF-8 bytes instead.

Comment: template <typename T>
void fromUTF8(const string& source, basic_string<T, char_traits<T>, allocator<T>>& result)
{
 wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<T>, T> convertor;
 result = convertor.from_bytes(source);
}                                                                                    Using codecvt i converted it to chinese and stored in wstring. Now my problem is with the RapidJSON am not able to write and construct JSON Body.